# What is IAP (Identity Aware Proxy) ? How does it help a company to use web apps privately?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

What is IAP (Identity Aware Proxy)? How does it help a company to use web apps privately throughout the world?
What is the relation between GCP App Engine and IAP?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is quite good [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap) on GCP pages regarding IAP. I think you will find anwser for first two questions.

When it comes to last question. App Engine is completely different product, but of course both can be combined. App Engine is serverless solution for developing apps. This means that you can deploy your apps in cloud without taking care of server beneath it.

You can find App Engine documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs).

So you can use use both App Engine and IAP or use them with other solutions, as you wish.

I hope it will help!